# Load csv and Image dataset in pytorch

Tags: image, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, pytorch

I am doing image classification with PyTorch. I have a separate Images folder and train and test csv file with images ids and labels . I don’t have any an idea about how to combine those images and ID and converting into tensors.

1. train.csv : contains all ID of Image like 4325.jpg, 2345.jpg,…so on and contains Labels like cat,dog.
2. Image_data : contains all the images of with ID name.

Comment: i answered like this one here https://stackoverflow.com/a/72337742/19173781

Answer (score 8):

You can create custom dataset class by inherting pytorch's [torch.utils.data.Dataset](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.Dataset).

The assumption for the following custom dataset class is

- csv file format is

| filename | label |
| --- | --- |
| 4325.jpg | cat |
| 2345.jpg | dog |

- All images are inside `images folder`.

```py
class CustomDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, csv_path, images_folder, transform = None):
        self.df = pd.read_csv(csv_path)
        self.images_folder = images_folder
        self.transform = transform
        self.class2index = {"cat":0, "dog":1}

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.df)
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        filename = self.df[index, "FILENAME"]
        label = self.class2index[self.df[index, "LABEL"]]
        image = PIL.Image.open(os.path.join(self.images_folder, filename))
        if self.transform is not None:
            image = self.transform(image)
        return image, label
```

Now you can use this class to load the training and test dataset using both csv file and image folder.

```py
train_dataset = CustomDataset("path - to - train.csv", "path - to - images - folder"  )
test_dataset = CustomDataset("path - to - test.csv", "path - to - images - folder"  )


image, label = train_dataset[0]
```

Comment: sir, why line 14 .....if self.transform is not None: shows syntax error

Comment: @RitikKumar, yes I forgot `)` on line 13. I have fixed now.

Comment: Great answer - only problem for me was that `df[index, "SDFSDF"]` raised an error - instead I used `df.loc[index]["SDFSDF"]` and it works fine.