# Reading labels in csv for images in PyTorch

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I am new to PyTorch.
The task - create train, validation and test classes.

Data:

1. CSV file with 2 columns

[image: Where id is name of the picture stored in train and test1 directories]

Where id is name of the picture stored in train and test1 directories

2. Directories with train and test data images.

My code so far:

```
**import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import torch.utils.data
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torchvision
from torchvision import transforms
from PIL import Image
##transforms
transforms = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize(64),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize(mean = [0.485, 0.456, 0.406],
                        std = [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
])
##dataloader
dataset_path = "C:/Users/nikit/OneDrive/Desktop/PyTorch/train/train"
dataset = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(root = train_data_path, transform = transforms)
val_split = 0.2
dataset_size = len(dataset)
val_size = int(test_split * dataset_size)
train_size = dataset_size - val_size
train_data, val_data = torch.utils.data.random_split(dataset, [train_size, test_size])
##define test 
test_data_path = "C:/Users/nikit/OneDrive/Desktop/PyTorch/test1/test1"
test_data = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(root = train_data_path, transform = transforms)
##data load
batch_size = 64
train_data_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_data, batch_size = batch_size)
val_data_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(val_data, batch_size = batch_size)
test_data_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(test_data, batch_size = batch_size)**
```

**Please help me to connect the values with csv data**

Comment: Have you read the [tutorial for custom datasets](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/data_loading_tutorial.html#dataset-class)?

Comment: Does not really make much sense to me

Comment: You'll have to implement a custom dataset. I'd recommend you to read it again.

Answer (score 0):

```
train_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["img_name","label"])
train_df["img_name"] = os.listdir(path_train)
for idx, i in enumerate(os.listdir(path_train)):
    if "cat" in i:
        train_df["label"][idx] = 0
    if "dog" in i:
        train_df["label"][idx] = 1

train_df.to_csv (r'train_csv.csv', index = False, header=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating a Custom Dataset for your files
A custom Dataset class must implement three functions: **init**, **len**, and **getitem**. Take a look at this implementation; the FashionMNIST images are stored in a directory img_dir, and their labels are stored separately in a CSV file annotations_file.

In the next sections, we’ll break down what’s happening in each of these functions:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from torchvision.io import read_image

class CustomImageDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, annotations_file, img_dir, transform=None, 
target_transform=None):
    self.img_labels = pd.read_csv(annotations_file)
    self.img_dir = img_dir
    self.transform = transform
    self.target_transform = target_transform

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.img_labels)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        img_path = os.path.join(self.img_dir, self.img_labels.iloc[idx, 0])
        image = read_image(img_path)
        label = self.img_labels.iloc[idx, 1]
        if self.transform:
            image = self.transform(image)
        if self.target_transform:
            label = self.target_transform(label)
        return image, label
```